# When looping through an array of object properties, how can I return an array value given an existing key?

Tags: php, arrays, object

If `$myObj` is:

```
$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj = array(1 => 100, 2 => 200, 3 => 300);
echo $myObj[1]; // returns 100, as expected
```

But when iterating through an array of properties like so:

```
$properties_array = array('property_one','property_two');
// and $myObj looks like $myObj->property_one = array(0 => 12345);
foreach ($properties_array as $property) {
    echo $property;
    // returns property name, as expected

    print_r($myObj->$property);
    // returns an array, as expected (ex. Array([0] => 12345))

    echo $myObj->$property[0];
    // expected '12345', instead throws an error: 'Undefined property: stdClass::$myObj'
}
```

Why would `print_r($myObj->$property);` work as expected, but `echo $myObj->$property[0];` throw an error?

Comment: BTW what is `$properties_array` structure..??can you show us..??

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help. Very straight forward: `$properties_array = array('property_one','property_two');` and `$myObj` is something like `$myObj->property_one = array(0 => 12345);`

Comment: Have you tried doing `echo $myObj->{$property}[0];` ?

Comment: @Vallel, No, but that was it! Thanks. Add as answer and I'll accept it. That was so frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing `echo $myObj->{$property}[0];`

Comment: Thanks again. Out of curiosity, do you know why that works? Or have a php reference for that?

Comment: That works because you were trying to get access to an array that does not exists. The array is `$myObj->property_one` not `$property`. You can read more about that in http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

Use key and value concept

```
  foreach ($properties_array as $key=>$property) {
       echo $property;//100
       echo $key;//1

  }
```

while echoing std class object,unable to access object